# minmal and comprehensive Hibernate architecture

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

[Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-overview-minimal) mention about two type of architectures supported in hibernate, a minimal and comprehensive architecture. I would like to know what minimal architecture refers to? An example would be helpful.

As per my understanding most of the times we always provide jdbc/datasource details as hibernate config and thats all! We let hibernate manage connection pooling and also transaction management and rollback. Does that mean we are using comprehensive architecture by default?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal architecture is the simplest possible Hibernate set-up. Below Hibernate there is JDBC, transactions are managed in code by Hibernate (which is only a thin layer over JDBC).

Comprehensive architecture is more involved. Connection lifecycle and transaction can be managed by some plug-in mechanism. For instance Java EE application server would provide connection management facility as well as transaction manager (JTA).

Similarly Spring Framework has its own transaction mamager, that might be used by Hibernate.

To sum-up. If you write standalone Hibernate application, you will probably relay on minimal architecture. Writing Spring based application or Java EE based application that id deployed to server you would probably use comprehensive architecture.